# Power BI automated deployment

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi

We have developed a set of Power BI reports and want to deploy these reports to higher environments. We have 4 environments in total to be deployed including Development.

- We have tried to use the Power BI deployment model using the portal based approach but it cannot deploy to more than 3 environments.
- We have tried the Git integration in Power BI and this did not work as the files are not stored in .pbix format in Git.

What is the way to deploy the Power BI reports automatically using Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 0):

To deploy the Power BI reports in Azure DevOps, we can use the Power BI Actions task from the extension: [Power BI Actions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maikvandergaag.maikvandergaag-power-bi-actions)

For example:

[image]

For more detailed steps to setup the Power BI Actions task, you can refer to this Blog: [Develop a CI/CD pipeline for Power BI report, using Azure DevOps](https://medium.com/@oscarojas/develop-a-ci-cd-pipeline-for-power-bi-report-using-azure-devops-6e97481f588a)

Comment: Thanks for the response, But since the extension is not officially supported by Microsoft, we won't be able to use this. Is there any other alternative to try.

Comment: @HillolSaha Currently there is no Microsoft extensions can do this action. And the extension in the answer is the most  popular. If you are not able to use it, you may need to consider using the script to achieve this . Refer to this sample: https://github.com/ivankragh/Articles/blob/master/PublishPowerBIReports.ps1 and this blog:https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/multi-stage-deployment-power-bi-reports-through-devops-kragh

Comment: Thanks for the response. Let us try this approach and I'll update the status here.

Comment: @HillolSaha Will wait for your update

Comment: @HillolSaha Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the method can help or have further questions.